# FFmpeg. Чтение и запись нескольких файлов из потока

Tags: c#, .net, потоки-данных, .net-core, ffmpeg

Проблема следующая.
Мне надо конвертировать видео в набор картинок через процесс ffmpeg.
Раньше я успешно это делал при помощи следующего кода:

```
public void VideoToImages1()
    {
        var inputFile = @"D:\testVideo.avi";
        var outputFilesPattern = @"D:\image%03d.jpg";

        using var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                Arguments = $"-y -i {inputFile} {outputFilesPattern}",
                FileName = "ffmpeg.exe"
            },
            EnableRaisingEvents = true
        };

        process.Start();

        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Теперь же мне необходимо передавать видео через входной Stream и получать данные из выходного Stream.
Для этого у меня следующий код. Он полностью рабочий так как я использовал его для конвертации видео и успешно передавал входные данные через Stream и получал выходные данные в через Stream и создавал корректный файл.

```
public void VideoToImages2()
    {
        var inputFile = @"D:\testVideo.avi";
        var outputFile = @"D:\resultImages.png";

        var process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                Arguments = "-y -i - -f image2 -",
                FileName = _ffmpeg
            },
            EnableRaisingEvents = true
        };

        process.Start();

        //Write input data to input stream
        var inputTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var input = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open))
            {
                input.CopyTo(process.StandardInput.BaseStream);
                process.StandardInput.Close();
            }
        });


        //Read multiple files from output stream
        var outputTask = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //Problem here
            using (var output = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create))
                process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CopyTo(output);
        });


        Task.WaitAll(inputTask, outputTask);

        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

Проблема здесь в том что вместо того чтобы создать файлы в директории по указанному паттерну он возвращает эти файлы в потоке.
В итоге я не знаю записать все файлы из Stream и как этот выходной обрабатывать так как он содержит множество файлов.
В данный момент у меня создается лишь 1 картинка.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Документацию по ffmpeg аргументам почитайте внимательней, stdout можно перенеправить в файл даже средствами шелла, а не выдумывать костыли. Так что нужно получить то в итоге? Как вы поняли что в потоке несколько файлов, если не можете их разделить? В любом случае, ответ скорее всего где-то в доках по ffmpeg. Но я не пойму, зачем использовать stdin и stdout, когда ввод и вывод с диска? Можно же пути задать в агрументах и готово. Есть рабочий код, пользуйтесь, зачем мудрить?

Comment: @aepot если не пытаться получить файлы в потоке а позволить процессу самому создать файл по паттерну то он создается множество файлов в указанной директории. Я хочу чтобы эти файлы не создавались на диске, хочу получить их в виде Stream или массива Stream и суметь эти стримы обрабатывать.

Comment: Покадрово видео воспроизводить чтоли? Ну читайте документацию, вам не картинки нужны, а данные для воспроизведения.

Comment: @aepot при указании выходного паттерна для файлов он ведь создает множество файлов на диске, а при указании выходного канала он ведь все выходные данные отправляет в выходной стрим. Вот мне как раз таки нужно как то эти данные из этого стрима получить. Когда выходным файлом является один файл то его легко считать кудато записать или обработать каким то образом. А в этом случае как быть с множеством файлов в выходном потоке? Я пытался искать по документации, дело как раз таки в том как работать с этим выходным потоком.

Comment: Вот в документации и должно быть написано, как работать с потоком. В худшем случае придется декодировать поток на лету, ведь читая JPEG или PNG кодек картинки знает, где конец файла. Либо битмапами, у них фиксированный размер фрейма с данными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено. Мне пришлось написать алгоритм по декодированию потока на наличие сигнатур файлов. Пока он плоховато работает и требует доработки.